# Can I set Windows Terminal to open command windows from "start" in a new tab?

Tags: windows-terminal

*Note: This is a question about [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), a new command-line shell as of 2019, not Windows Command Prompt command line shell that is included with Windows.*

If I am running cmd.exe in Windows Terminal, and I run `start cmd`, it opens a new command prompt window outside of Windows Terminal.

Is there any way to set Windows Terminal to "intercept" or otherwise harness that command so that it instead opens in a new tab in Windows Terminal (obviously running `cmd.exe`, in this example)?

Obviously, I can open a new tab with the mouse or a hotkey like Ctrl+Shift+2, but I'd like a way to do so from a batch file.

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question, try only typing "cmd" in your Terminal.  Is that the sort of result you are looking for?

Comment: No.  That starts cmd.exe in the same window and tab.  How do I start cmd.exe in a new tab in Windows Terminal?

Comment: Using "start <program>" always opens a new window of the program for me.  What exact version of Windows are you operating on?

Comment: I am using [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), not Command Prompt.  I wonder if you aren't aware of Windows Terminal?

Comment: I am not aware of Windows Terminal. Let me go educate myself really quick.

Comment: Might be possible, maybe there is hope using wt.exe. See: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Sep/03/Programmatically-Opening-Windows-Terminal-in-a-Specific-Folder

Comment: okay, wt creates a new terminal window, but you can't get it to make new tabs yet. seems to not respond to the commandline parameters just yet.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with Windows Terminal from version 0.9 onwards.

```
wt -d . ; new-tab -d C:\ pwsh.exe
```

> Opens the Terminal with two tabs. The first is running the default
>   profile starting in the current working directory. The second is using
>   the default profile with pwsh.exe as the "commandline" (instead of the
>   default profile’s "commandline") starting in the C:\ directory.

There are more examples on how to use this in the release notes of Windows Terminal 0.9: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-v0-9-release/

Comment: Is there any way to open a new tab from inside the terminal itself?

Comment: No, ```Windows Terminal is not yet capable of opening new tabs or panes in an existing instance.```  See :https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=linux#open-a-new-profile-instance @PatrickSzalapski

Comment: Yes, now there is an option: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=linux#target-a-specific-window

Comment: Use `wt -w 0 nt -d . cmd /k .\my-command.bat` if you want to start a command in the old shell.